# Overriding sleep method in Tank battle program

Tags: overriding, subclass, sleep

So my class is having a tank battle on Tuesday, and we were each designing logic for a tank. Our teacher designed out API and everything we'll need, and we simply must use what he gave us, however, he encouraged us to "cheat".

There is a sleep method that causes the tank to pause after doing many actions, and I was wondering how I might go about overriding this so it skips or nullifies the sleep.

```
void sleep(int ns) {
    try {
        Thread.currentThread().yield();
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(ns*100);
        Thread.currentThread().yield();
    } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
        ;
    }
}
```

Also, I was considering finding a way that my tank could not die when struck, but I had little success with that as well, there are two methods which affect this aspect of the game, which are checkDead() and kill(): (assuming dead is a boolean with value false)

```
void checkDead() {
    if(dead) throw new Error("Tank "+id+" is Dead");
}

final void kill() {
    synchronized(g) {
        if(dead)
            return;
        log("kill()");
        dead = true;
        logState();
        if(g.board[pos.x][pos.y]==this)
            g.board[pos.x][pos.y] = null;
    }
}
```

See, I attempted overriding them both with and without the @override, but I'm not sure why it won't hide the superclass's methods. Can anyone give me tips for any one or all of these issues?

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good idea to tell you what your teacher is hoping you'll discover for yourself.

Comment: Well, maybe you can offer me some insight then. For instance, I changed the code in the superclass for sleep to where instead of multiplying (ns*100), I made it (ns*0), and it worked! However when trying to do it in my subclass to override, it won't inherit, and when using @Override I get an error saying the method doesn't override a method from the supertype. Is there some syntax element I'm not getting?

Answer (score 1):

Notice the **final** definition in the method? Assuming you're using Java, you'll find that that is a method that can't be overriden or extended. See Java documentation or Wikipedia for details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_(Java). Show the API that your professor created, and it might explain how damage, death, and states are changed. I'm assuming he has a service-based architecture in terms of recording (and reporting) state changes...

I'm not going to give you suggestions on how to **Kobayashi Maru** the exercise - it's your philosophy that defines your tactics.

But if I may make one suggestion, consider reading [Sun Tzu's The Art of War](http://suntzusaid.com/), especially when attempting to game your opponents or the system.

Comment: That makes sense that he would make kill() final for that reason, but I'm still not sure about sleep..
Here is a link to the API: http://stevenrbrandt.com/tanks/docs/

Comment: There are more specifications that are covered in the API that would need to be documented (i.e. what's the cost of Scan, what's the limit of actions that can be taken in a Tank's turn - drive, aimTurret, etc., what are the end game conditions - damage, etc.) Off the cuff, I can see some technical decisions I'd make in a Tank subclass to test a "cheating" strategy. Consider Sun Tzu's #7: maneuvering (http://suntzusaid.com/book/7)